# Moving Overleaf project to the TexShop

Tags: overleaf, mac, texshop

[image]
On the screenshot is a structure of my PhD thesis as a Latex project in Overleaf. As you can see, it consists of multiple subfiles and subfolders.

Now, I am trying to compile this project offline using TexShop on Mac, but still failing to do so.

So far, I found on Overleaf forums that I need to add LatexMK file in the root of the project and then "typeset" the file "General.tex" to get a pdf version. I was trying to do so but without any success. I will appreciate any help with it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  TeXShop is a front end, not actually TeX.  You will need to install MacTeX or TeXLive.  You will also need to download the entire project from Overleaf: go to Menu in the upper left and Download the zipped Source.  Community Bot is requesting that you let us know which of those you're having trouble with, or which other step you're stuck at.

Comment: I have TeX on Mac and, of course, I have downloaded the entire project from Overleaf which you can see on the uploaded screenshot. I can "typeset" tex files which consist of an entire project in TexShop, but I can't typeset the projects which have more complicated structure like in the screenshot and required multiple iterations.

Comment: So you're opening "General.tex" in TeXShop and typesetting that.  What happens?  "without any success" doesn't tell us much.